# TileSource XYZ: asynchronous tileUrlFunction

Tags: openlayers

I am building an openlayers app which allows user to use offline tile images stored in IndexedDB as blobs:

```js
export async function getOfflineTileURL(coordinates) {
  // input: coordinates[zoom, column, tile]
  let row = await db.tiles.get({
    zoom: coordinates[0],
    column: coordinates[1],
    tile: coordinates[2]
  })

  if (row) {
    // if tile image exists in database, return its URL
    return URL.createObjectURL(row.blob)
  } else {
    return
    // TODO: return URL to online source as backup
  }
}
```

`db` is [Dexie.org](https://dexie.org/docs/Table/Table.get()) database (wrapper for IndexedDB).

I want to use `tileUrlFunction` to return URL for the requested tile:

```js
new TileLayer({
          source: new XYZ({
            tileUrlFunction: async(tileCoord) => {
              return await getOfflineTileURL(tileCoord)
            }
          })
        })
```

I cannot use `url` property in XYZ source because I cannot control output of `URL.createObjectURL`, it's just random string (ex. `blob:http://localhost:5173/a0cdebd5-df03-4134-9e93-b4d8ad888d6d`

And I cannot use titleURLFunction, because my code has to be async (Dexie and IndexedDB are asynchronous) and openlayers function only works synchronously (titleURLFunction from the code above returns `http://localhost:5173/[object%20Promise]`)

Is there a way I can make it work?

Comment: I am working on a similar project. Are you able to share the code where you save tiles into indexedDB?

Comment: Sure @user3289328 
https://gist.github.com/patrykkalinowski/45b610532b2710d91f2e39145c0469bf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done via the `tileLoadFunction`, which is asynchronous

```
tileLoadFunction: async function (tile, src) {
  const coordinates = tile.getTileCoord();
  let row = await db.tiles.get({
    zoom: coordinates[0],
    column: coordinates[1],
    tile: coordinates[2]
  })

  const image = tile.getImage();
  if (row) {
    // if tile image exists in database, return its URL
    const result = URL.createObjectURL(row.blob);
    image.addEventListener('load', function() {
       URL.revokeObjectURL(result);
    });
    image.src = result;
  } else {
    image.src = src;
  }
}
```